# Trying to match this regex in java:

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
"value":"ValueNumber1","label":"Peppe "},{"value":"ValueNumber2","label":"LoL"
```

I would like to split this string and get only the content of "value", in this case for example I would like to retrieve "ValueNumber1" and "ValueNumber2" (without double quotes).

I have tried something like this but without success:

```
StringToBeParsed.split("value\":\"+.\""));
```

Do you have any suggestion ? 
Tnx in advance.

Comment: Is that a part of some bigger JSON string?

Comment: @RohitJain yes it is.

Comment: Then use a JSON parser.

Comment: @RohitJain Are you aware of if it is exist any parser parsing all the keys "value" for example into a List?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: share the complete JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
value":"(.*?)"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qV3wA8/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [9-21]  `ValueNumber1`
MATCH 2
1.  [51-63] `ValueNumber2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Json**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "{\"values\":[{\"value\":\"ValueNumber1\",\"label\":\"Peppe\"},{\"value\":\"ValueNumber2\",\"label\":\"LoL\"}]}";
        JSONObject jObject;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray the_json_array = jObject.getJSONArray("values");

            int size = the_json_array.length();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
                JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println(another_json_object.get("value"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```